# How can I bold the title in YAML Header?

Tags: r, markdown

I have a question regarding R Studios. I have to create a pdf report in R. My problem: I don't know how to bold the title and subtitle in the YAML Header. I can't choose the bold option there.

Thanks

I already tried everything I know

Comment: Do you mean **bold** ? If so, you just put double asterisks around the text, inside the quote marks. For example:  `title: "**My Title**"`

Comment: Great, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Markdown formatting inside the quoted text, like so:

```
---
title: "**My Title**"
subtitle: "**My subtitle**"
---
```